# Microsoft office cannot find the input table or query

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I am trying to migrate an access database from 2000 to 20007 version. I have two .mdb files one used as a front end and the other containing only the back end tables. I performed all the necessary initialization for the migration like export of table, extension with .accd, etc.. But when i execute the following code , i get an error " Microsoft office cannot find the input table or query . Check spelling and so".

```
    set Db=currentDb
    SQLText ='some sql query'
    Db.OpenRecordset(SQLText, dbOpenDynaset)
```

When i tried to output the value of Db with a msgbox (MSgbox Db), it shows the message "ABC, type mismatch", where ABC is the function name. But, Msgbox Db.name showing the correct database name. But, the same code has been running fine on the older version.

Please help me on this

Comment: Please show the actual code ! I am sure it is not going to hurt.

Comment: Did you link the tables in the new DB?

Comment: You mean export the tables?. I did the export of the tables from the .accdb file with back end tables to the .accdb file with the user interface. I think it's the working when i access the database tables through the code.

Comment: @PaulFrancis and error number is 3078

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you do not have to "migrate" to a different version persay. You only have to import everything from an MDB to ACCDB file. That is all. Scratch whatever you have done, start afresh.

1. Create a new "empty" accdb file, then using the options under
   External Data-> Import/Link From Access. Select the **Front End** Access
   file. Use the Option **IMPORT** Forms, Report etc., select all Forms, Reports, Queries, Mods then click OK. This
   will import all objects.
2. Create a new "empty" accdb file, then using the options under
   External Data-> Import/Link From Access. Select the **Back End** Access file. Use the Option IMPORT Forms, Report etc., select all tables and click OK. This will import all the tables over to the new file.
3. Now open up your **new "front end"** (the one with accdb extension). Under External Data -> Import/Link. Select the **new "back end"** (the one with the accdb extension). Use the **Link to the Data Source** option. Then select all tables and click OK.

Now perform a Compact & Repair, follow it with a Compile of the VBA code.

The whole strategy will fail if you have a backend DB in a different platform like SQL or Oracle.

Comment: I did what u said. No luck..:(

Comment: can you ZIP your old "mdb" files removing every bit of data, just the table structures, probably a few forms. Upload it using DropBox/OneDrive? I will play with it and get back to you?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot be able to do that since it's a company data and i dont have access to dropbox here. Please excuse me